# on php page how to insert row after nth row using mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have successfully connected to mysql database and display results in a table on a php webpage.  I would like to add an extra row in the middle of the table so that I can display an image advertisement.  Do this in php or javascript? how do I integrate with current code?

```
--include file starts here
if  (mysqli_num_rows($sorc300res) < 1) {
$display_block = "<p><em>No topics exist.</em></p>";
} else {
while ($sorc300row = mysqli_fetch_array($sorc300res)) {
$sorc300arycustctr++;
$sorc300arycust[$sorc300arycustctr][1] = $sorc300row['audDt']);
$sorc300arycust[$sorc300arycustctr][2] = $sorc300row['audID'];
}
------end include file
----- begin php webpage 
<? php>
$holdcount     = 0;
$holdlistcolor = '';
for ($holdcount=1; $holdcount <= $sorc300arycustctr; $holdcount++) {
$holdlistcolor  = ($holdlistcolor == 'white' ? '#efefef' : 'white');
$sv300AudDt               = $sorc300arycust[$holdcount][1];
$sv300AudID               = $sorc300arycust[$holdcount][2];
?>
<td><?php echo $sv300AudDt; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $sv300AudID; ?></td>
</tr>
<? } php>
--end php file
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$holdlistcolor = '';
$middle = intval(($sorc300arycustctr/2));
for ($i=1; $i <= $sorc300arycustctr; $i++) {
$holdlistcolor  = ($holdlistcolor == 'white' ? '#efefef' : 'white');
$sv300AudDt               = $sorc300arycust[$i][1];
$sv300AudID               = $sorc300arycust[$i][2];
if($i==$middle){
echo '<tr><td>custom message</td><td>custom message</td></tr>';
}
echo '<tr><td>'.$sv300AudDt.'</td><td>'.$sv300AudID.'</td></tr>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Worked great!  Thanks much and have a great week.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("tr:eq(index)").after("<tr><td>x</td><td>y</td></tr>");
});
```

Comment: Get html by ajax based from db and insert on ajax success!!